# SonarQube unable to scan

Tags: sonarqube, sonarqube-scan

We have a github workflow using github actions the to perform sonar scan each time a push request event happen. We lately just updated the sonar version from 9.8 to LTS (docker)

After the upgrade it gives us this error on a sample push request event. Please advise what could be missed on the upgrade.

```
WARN: Property 'sonar.password' is deprecated. It will not be supported in the future. Please instead use the 'sonar.login' parameter with a token.
INFO: Load project repositories
INFO: ------------------------------------------------------------------------
INFO: EXECUTION FAILURE
INFO: ------------------------------------------------------------------------
INFO: Total time: 1:32.691s
INFO: Final Memory: 15M/54M
INFO: ------------------------------------------------------------------------
ERROR: Error during SonarScanner execution
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to load component class org.sonar.scanner.scan.filesystem.ProjectFileIndexer
    at org.sonar.core.platform.SpringComponentContainer.getComponentByType(SpringComponentContainer.java:139)
    at org.sonar.scanner.scan.SpringProjectScanContainer.doAfterStart(SpringProjectScanContainer.java:363)
    at org.sonar.core.platform.SpringComponentContainer.startComponents(SpringComponentContainer.java:188)
    at org.sonar.core.platform.SpringComponentContainer.execute(SpringComponentContainer.java:167)
    at org.sonar.scanner.bootstrap.SpringGlobalContainer.doAfterStart(SpringGlobalContainer.java:137)
    at org.sonar.core.platform.SpringComponentContainer.startComponents(SpringComponentContainer.java:188)
    at org.sonar.core.platform.SpringComponentContainer.execute(SpringComponentContainer.java:167)
    at org.sonar.batch.bootstrapper.Batch.doExecute(Batch.java:72)
    at org.sonar.batch.bootstrapper.Batch.execute(Batch.java:66)
    at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.internal.batch.BatchIsolatedLauncher.execute(BatchIsolatedLauncher.java:46)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.internal.IsolatedLauncherProxy.invoke(IsolatedLauncherProxy.java:60)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy0.execute(Unknown Source)
    at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.EmbeddedScanner.doExecute(EmbeddedScanner.java:189)
    at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.EmbeddedScanner.execute(EmbeddedScanner.java:138)
    at org.sonarsource.scanner.cli.Main.execute(Main.java:126)
    at org.sonarsource.scanner.cli.Main.execute(Main.java:81)
    at org.sonarsource.scanner.cli.Main.main(Main.java:62)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'org.sonarsource.scanner.api.internal.IsolatedClassloader@741a8937-org.sonar.scanner.scan.filesystem.ProjectFileIndexer': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 7; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'org.sonarsource.scanner.api.internal.IsolatedClassloader@741a8937-org.sonar.scanner.scan.filesystem.FileIndexer': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 6; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'org.sonarsource.scanner.api.internal.IsolatedClassloader@741a8937-org.sonar.scanner.scan.filesystem.MetadataGenerator': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'org.sonarsource.scanner.api.internal.IsolatedClassloader@741a8937-org.sonar.scanner.scan.filesystem.StatusDetection': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'projectRepositories' defined in org.sonar.scanner.repository.ProjectRepositoriesProvider: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.sonar.scanner.repository.ProjectRepositories]: Factory method 'projectRepositories' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Fail to request url: ***batch/project.protobuf?key=takot-stf&branch=develop
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:800)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(ConstructorResolver.java:229)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireConstructor(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1372)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1222)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:582)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:542)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:333)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:233)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveNamedBean(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1284)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveNamedBean(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1245)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveBean(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:494)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBean(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:349)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBean(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:342)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1174)
    at org.sonar.core.platform.SpringComponentContainer.getComponentByType(SpringComponentContainer.java:137)
    ... 20 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'org.sonarsource.scanner.api.internal.IsolatedClassloader@741a8937-org.sonar.scanner.scan.filesystem.FileIndexer': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 6; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'org.sonarsource.scanner.api.internal.IsolatedClassloader@741a8937-org.sonar.scanner.scan.filesystem.MetadataGenerator': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'org.sonarsource.scanner.api.internal.IsolatedClassloader@741a8937-org.sonar.scanner.scan.filesystem.StatusDetection': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'projectRepositories' defined in org.sonar.scanner.repository.ProjectRepositoriesProvider: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.sonar.scanner.repository.ProjectRepositories]: Factory method 'projectRepositories' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Fail to request url: ***batch/project.protobuf?key=takot-stf&branch=develop
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:800)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(ConstructorResolver.java:229)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireConstructor(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1372)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1222)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:582)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:542)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:333)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:276)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1391)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1311)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveAutowiredArgument(ConstructorResolver.java:887)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:791)
    ... 36 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'org.sonarsource.scanner.api.internal.IsolatedClassloader@741a8937-org.sonar.scanner.scan.filesystem.MetadataGenerator': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'org.sonarsource.scanner.api.internal.IsolatedClassloader@741a8937-org.sonar.scanner.scan.filesystem.StatusDetection': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'projectRepositories' defined in org.sonar.scanner.repository.ProjectRepositoriesProvider: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.sonar.scanner.repository.ProjectRepositories]: Factory method 'projectRepositories' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Fail to request url: ***batch/project.protobuf?key=takot-stf&branch=develop
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:800)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(ConstructorResolver.java:229)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireConstructor(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1372)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1222)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:582)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:542)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:333)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:276)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1391)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1311)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveAutowiredArgument(ConstructorResolver.java:887)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:791)
    ... 50 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'org.sonarsource.scanner.api.internal.IsolatedClassloader@741a8937-org.sonar.scanner.scan.filesystem.StatusDetection': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'projectRepositories' defined in org.sonar.scanner.repository.ProjectRepositoriesProvider: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.sonar.scanner.repository.ProjectRepositories]: Factory method 'projectRepositories' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Fail to request url: ***batch/project.protobuf?key=takot-stf&branch=develop
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:800)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(ConstructorResolver.java:229)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireConstructor(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1372)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1222)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:582)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:542)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:333)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:276)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1391)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1311)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveAutowiredArgument(ConstructorResolver.java:887)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:791)
    ... 64 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'projectRepositories' defined in org.sonar.scanner.repository.ProjectRepositoriesProvider: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.sonar.scanner.repository.ProjectRepositories]: Factory method 'projectRepositories' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Fail to request url: ***batch/project.protobuf?key=takot-stf&branch=develop
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:658)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:486)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1352)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1195)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:582)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:542)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:333)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:276)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1391)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1311)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveAutowiredArgument(ConstructorResolver.java:887)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:791)
    ... 78 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.sonar.scanner.repository.ProjectRepositories]: Factory method 'projectRepositories' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Fail to request url: ***batch/project.protobuf?key=takot-stf&branch=develop
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:185)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:653)
    ... 92 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Fail to request url: ***batch/project.protobuf?key=takot-stf&branch=develop
    at org.sonarqube.ws.client.HttpConnector.doCall(HttpConnector.java:208)
    at org.sonarqube.ws.client.HttpConnector.get(HttpConnector.java:125)
    at org.sonarqube.ws.client.HttpConnector.call(HttpConnector.java:112)
    at org.sonar.scanner.bootstrap.DefaultScannerWsClient.call(DefaultScannerWsClient.java:87)
    at org.sonar.scanner.repository.DefaultProjectRepositoriesLoader.load(DefaultProjectRepositoriesLoader.java:49)
    at org.sonar.scanner.repository.ProjectRepositoriesProvider.projectRepositories(ProjectRepositoriesProvider.java:45)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:154)
    ... 93 more
Caused by: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: timeout
    at okhttp3.internal.http2.Http2Stream$StreamTimeout.newTimeoutException(Http2Stream.kt:675)
    at okhttp3.internal.http2.Http2Stream$StreamTimeout.exitAndThrowIfTimedOut(Http2Stream.kt:684)
    at okhttp3.internal.http2.Http2Stream.takeHeaders(Http2Stream.kt:143)
    at okhttp3.internal.http2.Http2ExchangeCodec.readResponseHeaders(Http2ExchangeCodec.kt:96)
    at okhttp3.internal.connection.Exchange.readResponseHeaders(Exchange.kt:106)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.CallServerInterceptor.intercept(CallServerInterceptor.kt:79)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.kt:109)
    at org.sonarqube.ws.client.OkHttpClientBuilder.addHeaders(OkHttpClientBuilder.java:222)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.kt:109)
    at okhttp3.internal.connection.ConnectInterceptor.intercept(ConnectInterceptor.kt:34)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.kt:109)
    at okhttp3.internal.cache.CacheInterceptor.intercept(CacheInterceptor.kt:95)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.kt:109)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.BridgeInterceptor.intercept(BridgeInterceptor.kt:83)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.kt:109)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.RetryAndFollowUpInterceptor.intercept(RetryAndFollowUpInterceptor.kt:76)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.kt:109)
    at okhttp3.internal.connection.RealCall.getResponseWithInterceptorChain$okhttp(RealCall.kt:201)
    at okhttp3.internal.connection.RealCall.execute(RealCall.kt:154)
    at org.sonarqube.ws.client.HttpConnector.doCall(HttpConnector.java:206)
    ... 103 more
ERROR: 
ERROR: Re-run SonarScanner using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
```